# Determine if elements of a certain class have a certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very boring `.each()` loop:

```
var HasAnX = false;

$('#SomeContainer').find('.SomeClass').each(function () {

    if ($(this).text() === 'X') {

        HasAnX = true;
        return;
    }
});
```

Basically, I'm looping over all the elements to determine if at least one of them has an X. It works. But is there a more concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var HasAnX = $('#SomeContainer').find('.SomeClass:contains("X")').length > 0;
```